# Beamer: Errors of compilation

Tags: beamer

Good afternoon
can somebody help, i can't figure out where is the errors
here is the link for the log file: https://pastebin.com/3pjjd9rw

Comment: Could be a missing `}` on your first slide. Please add the `LaTeX` code to your question.

Comment: It would be far more helpful to post the code than the log file.